# How to scrape an interactive charts with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, chart.js

I'm using `scrapy` to scrape and crawl webpages.

I am interested in how to scrape this [page](https://www.canalturf.com/cotes/2019-04-15/maisons-laffitte/185850_prix-des-ecuries-du-chateau.html). As you can see there are several charts. But when I look at the source code, I do not find the values of the points, even when I search in the `<script>` tags.

How can I scrape each chart, with `x` as hour, and `y` as value of the odd?

Scrapy version: 1.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is on your webpage. Check in `script` tag variables `var cote_data_1`, `var cote_data_2`, etc. They should be available without JS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that **scrapes** the first chart data:

```
import scrapy
import ast


def find_between(s, start, end):
  return (s.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]


class CanalTurfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "CanalTurfSpider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.canalturf.com/cotes/2019-04-15/'
                  'maisons-laffitte/185850_prix-des-ecuries-du-chateau.html']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.xpath('//script').extract()[-1]
        chart1_data = find_between(data, "var cote_data_1 = ", ";")
        chart1_data = ast.literal_eval(chart1_data)
        yield {
            "chart1_data": chart1_data
        }
```

Output:

```
{'chart1_data': [{'elapsed': '12:25', 'value': 9.3}, {'elapsed': '12:35', 'value': 9.7}, {'elapsed': '12:45', 'value': 10}, {'elapsed': '12:55', 'value': 10.1}, {'elapsed': '13:05', 'v
alue': 10.6}, {'elapsed': '13:15', 'value': 10.6}, {'elapsed': '13:25', 'value': 11.2}, {'elapsed': '13:35', 'value': 11.3}, {'elapsed': '13:45', 'value': 13.1}, {'elapsed': '13:55', '
value': 14.7}, {'elapsed': '14:05', 'value': 18.8}, {'elapsed': '14:15', 'value': 18.8}]}
```

you can find variables in last script block.