# How to add double quotes in a char according to a pattern in python 3.X?

Tags: python, json

Related to a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713573/how-to-scrap-an-interactive-charts-with-scrapy/55713622#55713622) I did yesterday, I face a new problem.

I manage to **scrape**, but I have a specific issue with this:

```
'{cote_data_1 : [{"elapsed": "12:25", "value": 9.3},
{"elapsed": "12:35", "value": 9.7},{"elapsed": "12:45", "value": 10},
{"elapsed": "12:55", "value": 10.1},{"elapsed": "13:05", "value": 10.6},
{"elapsed": "13:15", "value": 10.6},{"elapsed": "13:25", "value": 11.2},
{"elapsed": "13:35", "value": 11.3},{"elapsed": "13:45", "value": 13.1},
{"elapsed": "13:55", "value": 14.7},{"elapsed": "14:05", "value": 18.8},
{"elapsed": "14:15", "value": 18.8}]}'
```

You will find the different steps of transformation below that I did to find this `str` object above.
My problem is to correspond to a json format, the pattern `cote_data_X` must be quoted. You can try it yourself on this [page](https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser) as I did.
The problem is I have got a whole `list` of this kind of `str` object (called `n_find_all` below), following the same pattern, but `cote_data_X` gives `cote_data_1`, `cote_data_2`, `cote_data_3` and so on, and `X` is not always in the same range. The last `X` could 5 or 25, or any number else.
So I would like to know how to do to double quote this pattern `cote_data_X` for each `str` object in the `list`. Like this I expect to join the `str` objects and transform it with `json.loads(str_joined)`.

I want to add that maybe you have others solutions to just obtain a python `dict` that I can return in the `item`. I accept it, but for the knowledge it would be fine too to know how to do it the way I showed because it could be more general than in a scraping problematic.

### Here the reproducible code.

```
scrapy crawl https://www.canalturf.com/cotes/2019-04-15/maisons-laffitte/185850_prix-des-ecuries-du-chateau.html
from re import findall
x=response.xpath('//div/script[8]').extract()
n=x[0].replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
n_find_all=findall('(var.*?];)',n) #you can check on https://regex101.com/
n_find_all=[i.replace('var ','').replace('=',':').replace(';','') for i in n_find _all] #to be json parse compatible
n_find_all=['{'+i+'}' for i in n_find_all] #adding the curly bracket
n_find_all[0] #now you find the same code at the top of the question.
```

python version 3.7.1

Comment: try module `dirtyjson` to read it

Comment: replace `var ` with `"` and you will have quote before `"cote_data_1`, replace ` = ` with `" :` and you will have quote after `cote_data_1"` Use both and you get `"cote_data_1"`

Comment: If you don't actually have problem with your code besides curiosity or willingness to improve, try out the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Comment: @lucasgcb I did not know there was another stack for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexes seem a little too complicated.

You would acquire `DATA` from the script tag as before – I removed the `Morris.Line` declarations for the sake of a simpler, shorter example, but it should work with the original data as well.

```py
import re
import json

DATA = """                          
                                    var cote_data_4 = [
                                        {"elapsed": "12:25", "value": 6.8},{"elapsed": "12:35", "value": 7.1},{"elapsed": "12:45", "value": 7.1},{"elapsed": "12:55", "value": 7.4},{"elapsed": "13:05", "value": 7.5},{"elapsed": "13:15", "value": 7.5},{"elapsed": "13:25", "value": 7.9},{"elapsed": "13:35", "value": 8.5},{"elapsed": "13:45", "value": 8.8},{"elapsed": "13:55", "value": 9},{"elapsed": "14:05", "value": 7.6},{"elapsed": "14:15", "value": 7.6}
                                    ];

                                    var cote_data_5 = [
                                        {"elapsed": "12:25", "value": 19.3},{"elapsed": "12:35", "value": 20.9},{"elapsed": "12:45", "value": 20.1},{"elapsed": "12:55", "value": 20.6},{"elapsed": "13:05", "value": 21},{"elapsed": "13:15", "value": 21},{"elapsed": "13:25", "value": 20.2},{"elapsed": "13:35", "value": 20.1},{"elapsed": "13:45", "value": 21.9},{"elapsed": "13:55", "value": 23.3},{"elapsed": "14:05", "value": 28.4},{"elapsed": "14:15", "value": 28.4}
                                    ];
"""

cote_data_re = re.compile(r'var (cote_data_.+?) = (\[.+?\]);', flags=re.DOTALL)

cote_datas = {}
for match in cote_data_re.finditer(DATA):
    var_name, value = match.groups()
    cote_datas[var_name] = json.loads(value)

print(cote_datas)
```

The output is, as expected,

```py
{'cote_data_4': [{'elapsed': '12:25', 'value': 6.8}, ...], 'cote_data_5': [{'elapsed': '12:25', 'value': 19.3}, {'elapsed': '12:35', 'value': 20.9}, ...]}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. Thank you. You're right when you say "Your regexes seem a little too complicated", I don't master it well. I am an absolute beginner with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `var` with `"` and you will have quote before `"cote_data_1`.

Replace `=` with `":` and you will have quote after `cote_data_1"`

Use both and you get `"cote_data_1"`

```
i.replace('var ','"').replace('=','":')
```

This will work even if you will have ie. `var hello_world = ...`

---

BTW: If you will get incorrect JSON then you can try to read it with module [dirtyjson](https://pypi.org/project/dirtyjson/)

Comment: You seem to forget this not always `cote_data_1`. The digit changes at each element of the list. I will try the solution of AKX as soon as possible.

Comment: My solution doesn't care for variable name - it doesn't have to be `cote_data_1` it can be `hello_world`, `abba`, `something_totaly_different_2019` and it will work too.

Comment: I am sorry you're right. I checked and it works. But AKX's solution doesn't require a new module `dirtyjson`, even if it is very interesting to know its existence. I hope you will not resent I accept the other solution, because even myself is a bit embarrassed because you propose something that does not change so much my code, and in the meantime this is right my code was `little too complicated`.

Comment: you don't understand - you don't need module `dirtyjosn`, you have to only add two `"` in you current code in line `i.replace('var ','"').replace('=','":')`. Nothing more. I mention `dirtyjson` only as BTW (By The Way). But AKX's code looks simple then yours so use/accept AKX's solution.